# Correct way to call methods in a controller class

Tags: python, pylons

I'm relatively new to Python and working on a Pylons app.

Consider the following controller:

```
class FooController(BaseController): 

   def doFoo(self, fooArg): 
       #do stuff
       #return stuff

   def doBar(self, barArg): 
       self.doFoo(barArg) #call A 
       FooController.doFoo(self, barArg) #call B
```

What (if anything) is the difference between call A and call B here?

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, nothing. Because when you do `self.<method_call>`, self is implicitly passed as the first parameter to `FooContoller.doFoo(<self>, arg)`.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks for confirming. Are you sure there isn't a pylons-specific (or even pylons-controller-specific) difference between them?

Comment: nope. this is pretty python specific. If you want to learn more about OO in Python, try reading Dusty's book on Python 3 OO from Packt. Its quite good.